# Search value by key in random/dynamic array

Tags: php, arrays

what is best way to search Multidimensional array be key.
like

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item1] => Array
                                (
                                    [item] => a
                                    [url] => xys.com
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [item2] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => xys.com
                                    [count] => 5
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [item3] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => abc.com
                                    [count] => 5
                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [item4] => Array
                                (
                                    [meta] => b
                                    [count] => 5
                                )

                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [item5] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => abc.com
                                    [count] => 5
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

i want to get the value of 1st occurrence or key "URL" and value should be "xys.com"

the array may be random/dynamic so i can't iterate it using it's key and i just want it to search by 1st occurrence of key

Thanks

Comment: Just to make it clear, do you want the first occurrence of 'url' key ?

Comment: yes it's php and i want to get the value of 1st occurrence of key 'URL' and it may be dynamic/random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and this function works well for above example:

```
function searchArrayValueByKey(array $array, $search) {
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)) as $key => $value) {
    if ($search === $key)
    return $value;
}
return false;
}
```